# kafka_exporter doesn't send metrics to prometheus

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, apache-zookeeper, prometheus

Can you help me with my installation?
I have kafka cluster on 3 nodes: kafka1:9092, kafka2:9092, kafka3: 9092
And I want to get metrics from these nodes.
I download node_exporter and installed it on one node - kafka1.
My service file last version:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus exporter for kafka.
Documentation=https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=prometheus
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/kafka_exporter --kafka.server=kafka1:9092 --kafka.server=kafka1:9092 --kafka.server=kafka1:9092
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

node_exporter server starts good, I see in log:

```
Jul 09 18:08:33 kafka1 systemd[1]: Started Prometheus exporter for kafka..
Jul 09 18:08:33 kafka1 kafka_exporter[5391]: time="2019-07-09T18:08:33+03:00" level=info msg="Starting kafka_exporter (version=1.2.0, branch=non-git, revision=non-git)" source="kafka_exporter.go:474"
Jul 09 18:08:33 kafka1 kafka_exporter[5391]: time="2019-07-09T18:08:33+03:00" level=info msg="Build context (go=go1.9.4, user=mockbuild@44b00b1726084a939a040a64de97977c, date=20180912-11:02:53)" source="kafka_expor
Jul 09 18:08:33 kafka1 kafka_exporter[5391]: time="2019-07-09T18:08:33+03:00" level=info msg="Done Init Clients" source="kafka_exporter.go:213"
Jul 09 18:08:33 kafka1 kafka_exporter[5391]: time="2019-07-09T18:08:33+03:00" level=info msg="Listening on :9308" source="kafka_exporter.go:499"
```

In prometheus config I added job:

```
  - job_name: 'Kafka exporter'
    static_configs:
    - targets: [
        '172.29.15.30:9308'
        ]
```

And I see in prometheus This job and target - it's in UP state, but, http://172.29.15.30:9308/metrics page not loading. It give me ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT Error.

If I add wrong kafka.server, kafka_Exporter stops after run with error:

```
ERRO[0000] Error Init Kafka Client                       source="kafka_exporter.go:210"
panic: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)
```

Because I think, it see kafka cluster.

What I did wrong? What I must troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka does not send any metrics to Prometheus. The Prometheus server will pull metrics from your metrics API.

But I can recommend that it is better to use official JMX exporter.

First download the agent:

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.9/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.9.jar
```

Then it's yaml file:

```
wget https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/raw/master/example_configs/kafka-2_0_0.yml
```

Now what you have to do is to set `KAFKA_OPTS` environment variable to run this exporter:

```
[Service]
...
Restart=no
**Environment=KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/home/morteza/myworks/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.9.jar=7071:/home/morteza/myworks/kafka-2_0_0.yml**
```

This is a summary of [Monitor Apache Kafka Using Grafana and Prometheus](https://link.medium.com/jDFwgkzDbY) article

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get these metrics from the kafka-exporter is having Prometheus scrape them. You can do this by [using annotation](https://www.weave.works/docs/cloud/latest/tasks/monitor/configuration-k8s/#per-pod-prometheus-annotations) on the kafka_exporter pod.

You can find here an example for a more holistic solution [see this guide](https://medium.com/@ranrubin/horizontal-pod-autoscaling-hpa-triggered-by-kafka-event-f30fe99f3948)

Please comment if something is unclear